# How to obfuscate Kotlin properties with R8?

Tags: android, kotlin, proguard, android-r8

I have a library on Kotlin I want to obfuscate almost completely but leave the public classes, properties and methods untouched. Here is an example of one of the public classes I intend to obfuscate:

```kotlin
class SomeClass(val propertyToShow: SomePublicClass, private val propertyToHide: SomeOtherPublicClass) {

    fun methodToShow(someArg: SomeArg) {
        // Some code
    }

    private fun methodToHide(someOtherArg: SomeOtherArg) {
        // Some more code
    }

}
```

The ProGuard file is based on a [typical library ProGuard file](https://www.guardsquare.com/manual/configuration/examples) and looks like this:

```
-keepattributes SourceFile,LineNumberTable

-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile

-dontwarn javax.annotation.**

-keepnames class okhttp3.internal.publicsuffix.PublicSuffixDatabase

-dontwarn org.codehaus.mojo.animal_sniffer.*
-dontwarn okhttp3.internal.platform.ConscryptPlatform

-keepattributes Signature

-keepattributes *Annotation*

-dontwarn sun.misc.**
-keep class com.google.gson.stream.** { *; }

-keep class * implements com.google.gson.TypeAdapterFactory
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonSerializer
-keep class * implements com.google.gson.JsonDeserializer

-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
  @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName <fields>;
}

-keep public class * {
    public protected *;
}

-keepclassmembernames class * {
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String);
    java.lang.Class class$(java.lang.String, boolean);
}

-keepclasseswithmembernames class * {
    native <methods>;
}

-keeppackagenames **
-keepattributes Exceptions,InnerClasses,Signature,Deprecated,SourceFile,LineNumberTable,*Annotation*,EnclosingMethod,Synthetic,PermittedSubclasses
-keepparameternames
-renamesourcefileattribute SourceFile
-keepclassmembers class **$WhenMappings {
    <fields>;
}
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }

-keep class kotlin.** { *; }
-keep class kotlin.Metadata { *; }
-keep class kotlin.reflect.** { *; }
-dontwarn kotlin.reflect.**
-dontwarn kotlin.**
-keepclassmembers class **$WhenMappings {
    <fields>;
}
-keepclassmembers class kotlin.Metadata {
    public <methods>;
}
-assumenosideeffects class kotlin.jvm.internal.Intrinsics {
    static void checkParameterIsNotNull(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers,allowobfuscation class * {
    @javax.inject.* *;
    @dagger.* *;
    <init>();
}

-keep class javax.inject.** { *; }
-keep class **$$ModuleAdapter
-keep class **$$InjectAdapter
-keep class **$$StaticInjection
-keep class dagger.** { *; }

-keepclassmembers class * extends java.lang.Enum {
    public static **[] values();
    public static ** valueOf(java.lang.String);
}

-keepclassmembers class * implements java.io.Serializable {
    static final long serialVersionUID;
    static final java.io.ObjectStreamField[] serialPersistentFields;
    private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream);
    private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream);
    java.lang.Object writeReplace();
    java.lang.Object readResolve();
}
```

Running `./gradlew assembleRelease` results in `.aar` file. The `SomeClass.class` from it looks like this (if we take a look at it via Android Studio)

```
public final class SomeClass public constructor(propertyToShow: SomePublicClass, propertyToHide: SomeOtherPublicClass) {
    
    public final val propertyToShow: SomePublicClass /* compiled code */

    private final val propertyToHide: SomeOtherPublicClass /* compiled code */

    public final fun methodToShow(someArg: SomeArg): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }

    private final fun a(someOtherArg: SomeOtherArg): kotlin.Unit { /* compiled code */ }
    
}
```

As we can see, the name of the private method has been obfuscated but its argument is not as well as the private property. It doesn’t matter if we obfuscate it with ProGuard or R8, the result is the same.

Is it possible to obfuscate private properties and private methods' arguments for Kotlin source code? Or is it pointless, since it will not interfere with others doing reverse engineering?

Comment: I will suggest to start out with using `-whyareyoukeeping` on the properties/types you have questions on. E.g. adding `-whyareyoukeeping class SomeOtherArg` and `-whyareyoukeeping class SomeClass { private SomeOtherPublicType propertyToHide; }`. When compiling the `-whyareyoukeeping` information is printed to stdout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer to this question was more or less explained in [this article](https://chameth.com/obfuscating-kotlin-proguard/). Basically the issue was that the code was indeed obfuscated properly but there was still Kotlin Metadata and Android Studio was reconstructing the code based on this Metadata.